# Read String by character combination from left in php

Tags: php

I need to read String and return combination of character. Like search Engine.

Example: "India"
Return: I,
        In,
        Ind,
        Indi,
        India,

```
$string = 'India';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
echo '<pre>';echo $string{$i};echo '</pre>';}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with "java"?

Comment: May be I can find some idea that convert to php code.

Comment: [code] $string = 'India';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
{
    echo '<pre>';
echo $string{$i};
echo '</pre>';
}

Comment: Maybe that would be a PHP problem?  Maybe the code you have shown us isn't Java?  Maybe you should remove the `java` tag ... 'cos it is irrelevant?  Or maybe you .... just like downvotes?

Comment: The code in your comment isn't Java either.

Comment: Removed Java tag

Comment: Can Anyone help please I need return character combination Like India, it would I,  In,  Ind,  Indi,   India

Comment: Consider adding the output you get. I don't know PHP but it looks like you are only printing the `i`th character while you appear to be wanting to print the first i characters instead. maybe you can use another for loop from 0 to i inside your loop to print all the characters from 0th position to ith position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr`

```
$string = 'India'; 
for ($i=0; $i <= strlen($string); $i++) 
{ 
    echo '<pre>'; 
    echo substr ($string,0,$i);
    echo '</pre>'; 

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
I
In
Ind
Indi
India
```

Comment: Awesome, Forget about substr(). Thank you so much.Still not able to do Vote, Your answered is correct

Comment: Do you accept it as a ans ? if this ans is correct.